# Rename SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE

Tags: configuration, cookies

Is there a way to rename the Sitecore cookie `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE`?  [Wappalyzer](https://wappalyzer.com/) [identifies](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/67bda26ebdc2e501132cafb2906a016bca8a497b/src/apps.json#L6579) a Sitecore site via this cookie, and we would like to stop it from doing so, whilst retaining the behaviour associated with the cookie.

Comment: +1 for getting this info out there! This is something that I have wanted to see Sitecore improve for quite a while now

Comment: This really should a configuration option. I have created a suggestion on https://sitecorecommunity.uservoice.com/forums/288676-community-ecosystem-sites/suggestions/17345056-rename-sc-analytics-global-cookie-cookie - please upvote this, so we can bring focus to this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With no obvious way of making Sitecore do our bidding, and me not finding any IIS configuration way of achieving this - I opt for a third solution. Enter a `HttpModule` to achieve this.

Function is fairly simple. Outgoing, any SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE will get removed and our own MY_COOKIE added, with the same value. Ingoing, any incoming MY_COOKIE will result in a SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE getting added.

Code looks like this:

```
namespace Website.CookieRenamer
{
    public class CookieRenamerModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;
            context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += Context_PostRequestHandlerExecute;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        private void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var application = (HttpApplication) sender;
            var context = application.Context;
            var trackingCookie = context.Request.Cookies["MY_COOKIE"];
            if (trackingCookie != null)
                WebUtil.SetCookieValue("SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE", trackingCookie.Value);
        }

        private void Context_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var application = (HttpApplication) sender;
            var context = application.Context;
            var trackingCookie = context.Response.Cookies["SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE"];
            if (trackingCookie != null)
            {
                WebUtil.SetCookieValue("MY_COOKIE", trackingCookie.Value);
                context.Response.Cookies.Remove("SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gets configured in the `<system.webServer>` section of `Web.config` like this:

```
<add type="Website.CookieRenamer.CookieRenamerModule, Website" name="CookieRenamer" />
```

And the desired end result comes out like this. Rename cookie as appropriate.

[image]

Comment: Sneaky solution ;-)

Comment: I believe it's called "thinking outside the box" ;-)

Comment: As a tiny remark, I would use the constant that Sitecore provides for the cookie name instead of hard-coding the same.

Comment: Yea. Would involve trying to reflect a private const though. Not sure how I would approach that.  Besides, when the Sitecore cookie is no longer hardcoded, this code becomes redundant :-)

Comment: Yes you're right, I overlooked the fact that it's private

Comment: You cheated...I like it!!!!!!! Very nice solution, Mark!

Comment: Now that's pretty cool. Does it matter where exactly you put this module relative to the existing modules?

Comment: Not 100% sure. I placed it last. I had to fiddle quite a bit to begin with - I tried "rewriting" the incoming/outgoing cookie. That doesn't work for a long list of complicated IIS reasons. Eventually I settled on this solution, as it ticks the boxes.

Comment: Although this is a workaround, it does solve the problem for now, which is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to do this. Have a look at the `Sitecore.Analytics.Web.ContactKeyCookie` class. You will find the following constant there:

```
private const string AnalyticsGlobalCookieName = "SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE";
```

The above means that the cookie name is hard-coded into Sitecore and cannot be changed.

In addition to the above, note also that this text is also hard-coded in all of the following locations (excluding locations where the constant is used) in the assemblies included natively in Sitecore 8.1u2:

[image]

#### My thoughts

IMHO, this is something that should be changed in the Sitecore code-base, as security could be improved by changing the cookie name in a way that prevents people from seeing that the site is a Sitecore site (which I assume is the reason why you want to do this).

#### Next Steps

I recommend that you file a Sitecore Support ticket for this issue. At least put it on their radar and explain the security hardening benefits to the system if they include support for this. They may give you a patch, and may even add this change to a future release.

Comment: There's a couple of user voice sites which you could submit this to? Not sure which would be most likely to be seen by the right people at Sitecore: see the top 3 results of this search: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sitecore%20user%20voice

Comment: @OwenNiblock: https://sitecorecommunity.uservoice.com/ is the official Sitecore UserVoice site to use.

Comment: Nice - I'll do that!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible without custom code. The string appears hardcoded twice in sitecore libraries.

Sitecore.Analytics.dll

```cs
namespace Sitecore.Analytics.Web
{
  public class ContactKeyCookie
  {
    private const string AnalyticsGlobalCookieName = "SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE";
    .....
    .....
  }      
}
```

Comment: just a note, decompiled constants show up as hard coded strings.  it's probably only hardcoded once, defining the constant.

Comment: Yeap, you are right Pete. Will remove second reference.